# Why is preg_match matching the last subpattern instead of the first?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match the first hexadecimal address from a line that can contain many hexadecimal addresses, but instead I get the last.

My request is:

```
preg_match('%.*(0x[0-9a-f]{8}){1}.*%', $v, $current_match);
```

where the `$v` is a string like:

```
Line: 2 libdispatch.dylib 0x36eaed55 0x36eae000 + 3413
```

I would want to get `0x36eaed55`, but my regular expression for `$current_match[1]` returns `0x36eae000` instead.

According to php documentation:
`$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `*` quantifier is greedy by default, so the first `.*` matches as much as possible while still allowing the entire expression to match. In this case, it means that `.*` will "gobble up" all of the hexadecimal constants but the last one, as `(0x[0-9a-f]{8}){1}` still needs to match.

One solution is to use the non-greedy operator `*?`. The first constant is found when using the following:

```
preg_match('%.*?(0x[0-9a-f]{8}){1}.*?%', $v, $current_match);
```

However, because you know that `$v` includes a hexadecimal constant, and you want the first one, then why not simply match against the pattern of the hexadecimal constant?

```
preg_match('%0x[0-9a-f]{8}%', $v, $current_match);
```

Even if you wanted the second, third, fourth, ... hexadecimal constant, you could use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with the same pattern:

```
preg_match_all('%0x[0-9a-f]{8}%', $v, $all_matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first `.*` tries to match as much as possible, so it matches your first hex as well. Try making it not greedy: `.*?`

Answer (score 4):

That's because your first `.*` is greedy. You can fix it by changing your regexp to:

```
preg_match('%(0x[0-9a-f]{8})%', $v, $current_match);
```

or

```
preg_match('%.*?(0x[0-9a-f]{8})%', $v, $current_match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ungreedy modifier, "U":

```
preg_match('%.*(0x[0-9a-f]{8}){1}.*%U', $v, $m);
```